# Service builder doesn't delete table in DB

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-service-builder

Hi all,

I'm using LR 6.1.

I created a new entity Called " Recommendation" in `service.xml` then a run `BuildServices` with `Ant` to generate the service builder Files.
Now I want to delete the Entity. So I Deleted if from `service.xml`, but nothing happens in Data base and the other files: The Database Table is here and the other generates File.

any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Liferay will never ever delete a table which has been in your service.xml but is now deleted. Also it will not delete any of the classes generated by a build-service command. For example it could be the case, that you refactored your portlet to 2 different projects. On a deploy, you don't want to lose all your data, only because the table is now defined in a different service.xml. So don't see this as a bug, more a security feature. If you want to delete the table, you have to issue a drop command on your database, and manually delete the Service files generated by Liferay Service Builder.

Comment: Funny how we both answer with almost exactly the same content at the same time. I'm going to delete mine.

Comment: I didn't see yours ;) But that only means we both think in the same ways. CU on DevCon!

Comment: posted 2 minutes after you, deleted 2 minutes after being written. See you in Darmstadt. If anybody is wondering what this is about: https://www.liferay.com/web/events2015/devcon